# Cannot get keycloak protocol mapper to invoke when retrieving a token

Tags: java, keycloak, mapper, keycloak-services

Keycloak 7.3.0GA Server

Using Library keycloak-services 3.4.3

Our team is having trouble getting our Keycloak protocol mapper to invoke during a token call:

- The mapper is registered at startup and is available in the list of mappers for our clients
- We add the mapper in the KC UI for our client
- When I try the "Evaluate" tab, the custom mapper (Stackoverflow Custom Mapper) does show in the list as one of the "Effective Protocol Mappers"
- However the mapper does not seem to be invoked from the Java side, I see nothing in my logs
- At this point we're just hoping to see our log statement for `transformAccessToken` and the test claim we've added

Evaluate Tab:
[Evaluate Tab Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lvh9e.png)

Java Code:

```
public class SoamProtocolMapper extends AbstractOIDCProtocolMapper implements OIDCAccessTokenMapper, OIDCIDTokenMapper, UserInfoTokenMapper{

public static final String PROVIDER_ID = "oidc-customprotocolmapper";
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SoamProtocolMapper.class);

private static final List<ProviderConfigProperty> configProperties = new ArrayList<ProviderConfigProperty>();

@Override
public List<ProviderConfigProperty> getConfigProperties() {
    logger.info("SOAM: inside getConfigProperties");
    return configProperties;
}

@Override
public String getDisplayCategory() {
    logger.info("SOAM: inside getDisplayCategory");
    return TOKEN_MAPPER_CATEGORY;
}

@Override
public String getDisplayType() {
    logger.info("SOAM: inside getDisplayType");
    return "Stackoverflow Custom Protocol Mapper";
}

@Override
public String getId() {
    logger.info("SOAM: inside getId");
    return PROVIDER_ID;
}

@Override
public String getHelpText() {
    logger.info("SOAM: inside getHelpText");
    return "some help text";
}

@Override
public AccessToken transformAccessToken(AccessToken token, ProtocolMapperModel mappingModel, KeycloakSession session,
        UserSessionModel userSession, AuthenticatedClientSessionModel clientSession) {
    logger.info("SOAM: inside transformAccessToken");
    token.getOtherClaims().put("stackoverflowCustomToken", "stackoverflow");

    setClaim(token, mappingModel, userSession, session);
    return token;
}

public static ProtocolMapperModel create(String name, boolean accessToken, boolean idToken, boolean userInfo) {
    logger.info("SOAM: inside create");
    ProtocolMapperModel mapper = new ProtocolMapperModel();
    mapper.setName(name);
    mapper.setProtocolMapper(PROVIDER_ID);
    mapper.setProtocol(OIDCLoginProtocol.LOGIN_PROTOCOL);
    Map<String, String> config = new HashMap<String, String>();
    mapper.setConfig(config);
    return mapper;
}}
```

Anything helps - thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question. There was a couple of lines of code missing in the `static` and `create` initialization methods. Here is a working example:

```
package com.github.bcgov.keycloak.soam;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.keycloak.models.ProtocolMapperModel;
import org.keycloak.models.UserSessionModel;
import org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.OIDCLoginProtocol;
import org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.mappers.AbstractOIDCProtocolMapper;
import org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.mappers.OIDCAccessTokenMapper;
import org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.mappers.OIDCAttributeMapperHelper;
import org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.mappers.OIDCIDTokenMapper;
import org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.mappers.UserInfoTokenMapper;
import org.keycloak.provider.ProviderConfigProperty;
import org.keycloak.representations.IDToken;


/**
 * SOAM Protocol Mapper
 */
public class SoamProtocolMapper extends AbstractOIDCProtocolMapper implements     OIDCAccessTokenMapper, OIDCIDTokenMapper, UserInfoTokenMapper {

private static final List<ProviderConfigProperty> configProperties = new ArrayList<ProviderConfigProperty>();

static {
    OIDCAttributeMapperHelper.addTokenClaimNameConfig(configProperties);
    OIDCAttributeMapperHelper.addIncludeInTokensConfig(configProperties, SoamProtocolMapper.class);
}

public static final String PROVIDER_ID = "oidc-soam-mapper";


public List<ProviderConfigProperty> getConfigProperties() {
    return configProperties;
}

@Override
public String getId() {
    return PROVIDER_ID;
}

@Override
public String getDisplayType() {
    return "Soam Protocol Mapper";
}

@Override
public String getDisplayCategory() {
    return TOKEN_MAPPER_CATEGORY;
}

@Override
public String getHelpText() { 
    return "Map SOAM claims";
}

protected void setClaim(IDToken token, ProtocolMapperModel mappingModel, UserSessionModel userSession) {
    token.getOtherClaims().put("test_claim", "Working!");
}

public static ProtocolMapperModel create(String name,
                                  String tokenClaimName,
                                  boolean consentRequired, String consentText,
                                  boolean accessToken, boolean idToken) {
    ProtocolMapperModel mapper = new ProtocolMapperModel();
    mapper.setName(name);
    mapper.setProtocolMapper(PROVIDER_ID);
    mapper.setProtocol(OIDCLoginProtocol.LOGIN_PROTOCOL);
    mapper.setConsentRequired(consentRequired);
    mapper.setConsentText(consentText);
    Map<String, String> config = new HashMap<String, String>();
    config.put(OIDCAttributeMapperHelper.TOKEN_CLAIM_NAME, tokenClaimName);
    if (accessToken) config.put(OIDCAttributeMapperHelper.INCLUDE_IN_ACCESS_TOKEN, "true");
    if (idToken) config.put(OIDCAttributeMapperHelper.INCLUDE_IN_ID_TOKEN, "true");
    mapper.setConfig(config);

    return mapper;
}
```

}

Comment: Hello, having the same problem now on Keycloak 7.4. Question, when is the create method invoked? Also, the methods ProtocolMapperModel.setConsentRequired and ProtocolMapperModel.setConsentText does not exist.

Comment: Hi Ross - we've upgraded to Keycloak 9; we did not have to make any changes to our code base (working as expected). I'm unsure where in the call stack the create method is being called.